Why the length of InputFilter is not equal to the paging size
I'm learning Apple's Accelerate Framework recently, and I tried to use InputFilter to decompress a compressed data. The demo code is as follows
    func decompressUsingInputFilter(_ compressedData: Data) {        
        let pageSize = 128
        var decompressedData = Data()
        var decompressIndex = 0
        let decompressBufferSize = compressedData.count
        let inputFilter = try! InputFilter(.decompress, using: .lzfse) { (length: Int) -> Data? in
            print("length=\(length)")
            let rangeLength = min(length, decompressBufferSize - decompressIndex)
            let subdata = compressedData.subdata(in: decompressIndex ..< decompressIndex + rangeLength)
            decompressIndex += rangeLength
            return subdata
        }
        while let page = try! inputFilter.readData(ofLength: pageSize) {
            decompressedData.append(page)
        }
        let decompressedString = String(data: decompressedData, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(decompressedString)
    }

I hope that InputFilter will decompress in pages of 128 bytes, but when I debugged it, I found that the length passed into the closure of InputFilter was 65536, which seems to be inconsistent with expectations. I want to know where the problem is.


The default bufferCapacity is 65536. The filter is paging into that buffer. You didn't specify a different bufferCapacity in your InputFilter(...) initializer, so you are getting the default.

I think the real question you should be concerned with is not how big length is but how big page is.

Thank u matt, I think I understand where 65536 comes from. But why pageSize is not passed as a parameter to the InputFilter closure? In the absence of external context, it seems that the InputFilter closure cannot determine the paging size.

There is a nice diagram of what you're doing. It explicitly says that a buffer of data is read.

Oh I see! The closure of InputFilter will read enough data at one time, and will not call the closure to get more until the readData method processes all data.
